# How to debug sphinx search using the indextool

Tags: sphinx

I ran `indextool` on an index that crashes sphinx when I use `indexer` on it.

The output of `indextool` shows many failures such as:

> FAILED, string offset out of bounds (row=18, stringattr=3, docid=3317, index=896070)

Can someone help me understand what the parameters (row, stringattr, docid, index) relate to so I can inspect the index csv file to try and see what's causing the failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are offsets within the generated index. Not in the original source dataset.

But also as far as I know `indextool` is only inspecting existing indexes. Running `indexer` is trying to create a new version of the index from the 'source' data. So if indexer is 'crashing' a proper index is NOT being built.

So `indextool` is inspecting some previous version, rather than the partly built index when indexer crashed! THat early version was already corrupted.

In short using `indextool` is a non starter. Need to debug using `indexer` instead.

Maybe try **--dump-rows** and/or **--verbose** options to `indexer` maybe will reveal something useful just before the crash happens?